# Design Time Error in MVVM Light for Windows Phone 8

Tags: mvvm-light, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm currently doing my first steps with the MVVM Light Toolkit. I want to open up an example WP8 project in Blend, but I'm getting the message Laurent also mentions in [his blog](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2012/11/11/a-fix-for-the-design-time-error-in-mvvm-light.aspx#feedback):

> “Could not load type ‘System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging’
>   from assembly ‘mscorlib.extensions’”

I've tried his fix and I cannot even reference the new patched dll files he offers for download. I'm getting this error message:

> A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 8 with this two files from the MVVM Light Toolkit:

- [Release Version 4.1](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/96993)
- [DLL Zip Package from the blog post](http://sdrv.ms/UUyOfU)

Did the fix work for any of you?

Thanks for your help,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known bug, possible solutions are described here:
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/401430

What you can do and what worked for me, is downloading latest source code of MVVM Light, remove all references to 'mscorlib.extensions', recompile it and you're good go.

In your project you then have to remove all references to 'mscorlib.extensions' as well, then it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer and the link to the discussion. If I understand correctly, there are some parts of the MVVM Light which reference to the INotifyPropertyChanging. These references should be removed from the DLL files Laurant offers in his blog post. If I compile the sources, I'll only see files for WP7 or WP71. Which should I use then for WP8, as there is a dedicated WP8 folder in the official installer version.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution right now. I personally use the WP7.1 MVVM Light library even in WP8 projects - it works just fine!

Comment: Hm I've compiled the source according to these instructions http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/building/ and executed the bat file. Then I've tried to reference the resulting release dlls files for WP71 from the binaries folder. I can add the Mvvmlight.extras and Mvvmlight file but not the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation nor System.Windows.Interactivity as I'm still getting this error: A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I installed the latest version of mvvm (GalaSoft.MvvmLight.4.1.24.0.msi).

I solved it by removing the references to GalaSoft and then using NuGet to reinstall the Portable MVVM libraries.  They have the NuGet name of MVVM LIght libraries only (PCL).  These seem to be compiled for the portable class libraries.